# Servlet example - File not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I made a servlet app in Eclipse with tomcat 6. I send some info from a form to a servlet. I get the error - `Firefox can't find the file at /C:/workspace-jee/Beer-v1/WebContent/html/SelectBeer.do.` How do I fix this problem ? Related info is given below. Please tell me if you need more info.

**HTML page -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Beer Selection Page</h1>
<form method = "POST" action="SelectBeer.do">

Select beer characteristics<p>
Color:
<select name ="color" size="1">
<option value="light">light</option>
<option value="amber">amber</option>
<option value="brown">brown</option>
<option value="dark">dark</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<center>
<input type = "SUBMIT">
</center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Beer-v1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>BeerSelect</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BeerSelect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BeerSelect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlet `BeerSelect` actually exists and has correct code.

**Tomcat startup logs -** I guess they call this `catalina` or something.

```
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;....more paths here.
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 878 ms
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/32  config=null
Apr 27, 2014 10:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 532 ms
```

**EDIT - My project structure inside eclipse jee:**

[image]

Comment: How have you opened the page? is it opened through eclipse? try to provide the below URL in IE and see what it gives http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/html/<NAMEOFHTML>.html

Comment: @AdityaKeyal - yes, the page opened through eclipse browser and also other browsers and I could send a parameter. But the servlet is not found, as mentioned in the intro of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to work around this problem:
option 1. Change the  action to read as below:

`<form method = "POST" action="/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do">`

Option 2. Change web.xml as below:

`<url-pattern>/html/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>`

Comment: I use eclipse browser. Option 1 error - `file:///C:/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do` Message = `This program cannot display the webpage`

Comment: Option 2 error - `file:///C:/workspace-jee/Beer-v1/WebContent/html/SelectBeer.do` Message = `This program cannot display the webpage`

Comment: I am a little confused. Your eclipse browser is opening the html page as a file protocol [denoted by file://]. A web app should open in HTTP protocol. Can you confirm when you open the HTML page what does the URL read?

Comment: Oh no ! It still reads from a file and not HTTP. `file:///C:/workspace-jee/Beer-v1/WebContent/html/form.html`

Comment: try to type `http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/html/form.html` manually in the browser and check. It should give you a 404 error.

Comment: Btw, I run my web app by `html > right click form.html > open with > web browser`.

Comment: ahh .. try instead `html> run as > Run On Server`

Comment: Correct - I get the error - `HTTP Status 404 - /Beer-v1/html/form.html`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51476/discussion-between-adityakeyal-and-borat-sagdiyev)

Comment: I am having some problems in chat. So, please bear with me. After `run on server`, i still get the error `HTTP Status 404 - /Beer-v1/html/Beer-v1/WebContent/html/SelectBeer.do` I don't know if this has something to do with having installed tomcat 6 as a service (besides as server in eclipse) and then stopped it from windows services.

Comment: to check,manually change the url to read `/Beer-v1/html/SelectBeer.do` or `/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do`

Comment: That did not work. Actually, in Eclipse the directory structure is like this `Beer-v1/WebContent/html/form.html`

Comment: the WebContent is ignored when deployed on a server. For more details look into WAR packaging. What does you web.xml's url pattern read currently?

Comment: same old `<url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>`

Comment: so if you URL will read `http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do` the request should goto your Servlet. After that put a SOP in the doGet and doPost method to confirm if the request reached.

Comment: now, when I try to run the form.html again, I get an error - `HTTP Status 404 - /Beer-v1/`

Comment: select the HTML page and try to run as server not the project. For the HTML page you URL should read `form.html` at the end.

Comment: I tried again with - html = `/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do`, web.xml = `<url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>`. Now it works !!! Cheers :) and thank you very much ! Wonder what was the problem before.

Comment: Same problem happened with a `JSP` i added. The jsp was "called" from a servlet. I fixed the path for that too. `/jsp/result.jsp`.

Comment: To call jsp from servlet use `request.getRequestDispatcher().forward()` look up more on the same on google for more idea